# How to rename image when it is already exist in folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am working on desktop application. In that I want to save image in folder with rename. If in folder the image is Img.jpg, then next time image will be Img1.jpg. I tried some code but I can't get result.

This is my Code

```
string folderPath1 = "E:\\CoachingClassImages\\HeaderInfoImages\\Logo";
if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath1))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath1);
}


//Save the file in folder
int count = 1;
string file = "E:\\CoachingClassImages\\HeaderInfoImages\\Logo" + logo_picname;
string extention=Path.GetExtension("jpeg|*.jpg|bmp|*.bmp|all files|*.*");
string fileLocation1 = file;
if (File.Exists(file))
{
    System.GC.Collect();
    System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1}){2}", logo_picname, extention, count++);

    File.Copy(fileLocation1, Path.Combine("E:\\CoachingClassImages\\HeaderInfoImages\\Logo", Path.GetFileName(tempFileName)), true);
}
else
{
    File.Copy(fileLocation1, Path.Combine("E:\\CoachingClassImages\\HeaderInfoImages\\Logo", Path.GetFileName(logo_location)), true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the file name, In your case you are specifying the values in the order of `logo_picname` - `extention` - `count` which will generate the file name as `Img(.jpg)3`. This is because String.Format` follows zero based indexing. you have to specify the parameters in the required order. One more thing I don't get what you are tried to get the the extension of the file, anyway the extension of the source file and destination file should be same, so that you should get the extension from the source file

So you should use like this:

```
string file = "E:\\CoachingClassImages\\HeaderInfoImages\\Logo" + logo_picname;
string extention=Path.GetExtension(file);
string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1}){2}", logo_picname,count++, extention);
// will give you the file name as Img(3).jpg if count is 3
```

Comment: un-lucky sir again i get error in extention variable like "Illigal character String".

Comment: @AjitNimbalkar: Take a look into the updated answer, Please let me know if you need any clarification

Comment: Its a string. i want to mention the extention with the image. so that's why i take this.

Comment: @unlucky sir, the same images are not incremented with numbers.

Comment: @AjitNimbalkar: Then what is happening there? Have you checked with break points

Comment: I checked it. but in folder the image are incremented only one time and this image will not set with the extention.

Answer (score -1):

**Using Logics**

```
1.Select all the String that has name (Img).

2.First of all you have to create an array (String myList[];) that will take all the file named (Img) existing in the folder . and then
take lenght for myList.Lenght(); 

3. again create an array an do this  For (int i =0;i<myList.Lenght();i++ ){ String myNew[i]=myList[i].getText().replaceAll("\\D+","");`enter code here`
}
```

//You Will Get  an array of numbers like this depending on your
    number on files in folders//
myNew []={1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on 
}

```
4.When u got the array with numbers take Lenght(); of that array 

5.Finally when u r creating a new file call this funtion and get the number on files in the folder which has same name and Lenght()+1 and
U are Done ! 


**I Hope You Will Understand my Logic . :)**
```